# How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty\lambda\left(I_0(\lambda)K_0(\lambda)-I_1(\lambda)K_1(\lambda)\right)\sin(\lambda z)J_0(\lambda t)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

While working on a flow problem, i came across non-trivial dual integral equations.
For their solution, ome must deal with the following infinite integral that involves a combination of Bessel and trigonometric functions:
$$
\int_0^\infty \lambda \left( I_0(\lambda) K_0(\lambda) - I_1(\lambda) K_1(\lambda) \right) \sin (\lambda z) J_0(\lambda t) \, \mathrm{d}\lambda \, ,
$$
wherein $J_0$ denotes the zeroth-order Bessel functions of the first kind, and $I_n$ and $K_n$ are, respectively, the $n$th order modified Bessel function of the first kind and the $n$th order modified Bessel function of the second kind.

In addition, i must evaluate the closely related integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \lambda \left( I_0(\lambda) K_0(\lambda) - I_1(\lambda) K_1(\lambda) \right) \cos (\lambda z) J_1(\lambda t) \, \mathrm{d}\lambda \, ,
$$
with $J_1$ denoting the first-order Bessel function.

i was wondering whether a closed analytical expression for the above integrals is possible. This is important to work on the next step of the calculations.

Any help or hints are highly appreciated and desirable!

Thanks and bests,
A

Comment: The function $\Phi(\lambda)$ can be simplified, as its denominator is the [Wronskian of $K_0(\lambda)$ and $I_0(\lambda)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.28.E2): $$I_0(\lambda)K_1(\lambda) + I_1(\lambda) K_0(\lambda)=1/\lambda$$

Comment: @PaulEnta Thanks for the great hint. i will try to dig into that and see.

Comment: Letting $f(z, t)$ be the function, $\int_0^z f(x,t) dx = \int_0^\infty \left( I_0(\lambda) K_0(\lambda) - I_1(\lambda) K_1(\lambda) \right) (1-\cos (\lambda z)) J_0(\lambda t) \, \mathrm{d}\lambda$, which might be easier to calculate

Comment: @VarunVejalla Can you solve that integral? It looks like complicated as well!

Comment: I don't think I could (at least not without a lot of work), but it definitely looks easier than the original.

Comment: @RonGordon Could the theorem of residues be applied here for such type of integrals? i see on you homepage that you thought quite a lot about those integration problems.